# Convert timestamps in Google Finance stock data to proper datetime

Tags: r, datetime, split, data.table, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert the timestamps in the stock data from Google Finance API to a more usable datetime format.

I have used `data.table::fread` to read the data [here](https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=300&p=30d&f=d,t,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=IBM):

```
fread(<url>)

      datetime    open     high      low    close  volume
1: a1497619800 154.230 154.2300 154.2300 154.2300     500
2:           1 153.720 154.3200 153.7000 154.2500 1085946
3:           2 153.510 153.8000 153.2000 153.7700   34882
4:           3 153.239 153.4800 153.1400 153.4800   24343
5:           4 153.250 153.3000 152.9676 153.2700   20212
```

As you can see, the "datetime" format is rather strange. The format is described in this [link](http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/44.html?task=view):

> The full timestamps are denoted by the leading 'a'. Like this: `a1092945600`. The number after the 'a' is a Unix timestamp. [...]
>
> The numbers without a leading 'a' are "intervals". So, for example, the second row in the data set below has an interval of 1. You can multiply this number by our interval size [...] and add it to the last Unix Timestamp.

In my case, the "interval size" is 300 seconds (5 minutes). This format is restarted at the start of each new day and so trying to format it is quite difficult!

I can pull out the index positions of where the day starts are by using `grep` and searching for "a";

```
newDay <- grep(df$V1, pattern = "a")
```

Then my idea was to split the dataframe into chunks depending on index positions then extend the unix times on each day separately followed by combing them back to a data.table, before storing.

[data.table::split](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/split.html) looks like it will do the job, but I am unsure of how to supply it the day breaks to split by index positions, or if there is a more logical way to achieve the same result without having to break it down to each day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `grepl` to search for `"a"` in "datetime", which results in a boolean vector. `cumsum` the boolean to create a grouping variable - for each  `"a"` (`TRUE`), the counter will increase by one.

Within each group, convert the first element to `POSIXct`, using an appropriate `format` and `origin` (and timezone, `tz`?). Add multiples of the 'interval size' (300 sec), using zero for the first element and the "datetime" multiples for the others.

```
d[ , time := {
  t1 <- as.POSIXct(datetime[1], format = "a%s", origin = "1970-01-01")
  .(t1 + c(0, as.numeric(datetime[-1]) * 300))
}
, by = .(cumsum(grepl("^a", datetime)))]

d
#       datetime                time
# 1: a1497619800 2017-06-16 15:30:00
# 2:           1 2017-06-16 15:35:00
# 3:           2 2017-06-16 15:40:00
# 4:           3 2017-06-16 15:45:00
# 5:           4 2017-06-16 15:50:00
# 6: a1500000000 2017-07-14 04:40:00
# 7:           3 2017-07-14 04:55:00
# 8:           5 2017-07-14 05:05:00
# 9:           7 2017-07-14 05:15:00
```

---

Some toy data:

```
d <- fread(input = "datetime    
a1497619800 
          1 
          2 
           3 
           4
a1500000000
3
5
7")
```

Comment: Nice solution! I always thought that you had to use either `format` or `origin`.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
DT[grep('^a', date), datetime := as.integer(gsub('\\D+','',date))
   ][, datetime := zoo::na.locf(datetime)
     ][nchar(date) < 4, datetime := datetime + (300 * as.integer(date))
       ][, datetime := as.POSIXct(datetime, origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'America/New_York')][]
```

you get:

> ```
>              date  close     high    low     open volume            datetime
>    1: a1500298200 153.57 153.7100 153.57 153.5900   1473 2017-07-17 09:30:00
>    2:           1 153.51 153.8700 153.33 153.7500 205057 2017-07-17 09:35:00
>    3:           2 153.49 153.7800 153.34 153.5800  70023 2017-07-17 09:40:00
>    4:           3 153.68 153.7300 153.42 153.5400  53050 2017-07-17 09:45:00
>    5:           4 153.06 153.7500 153.06 153.7200 120899 2017-07-17 09:50:00
>   ---                                                                       
> 2348:         937 143.94 144.0052 143.91 143.9917  36651 2017-08-25 15:40:00
> 2349:         938 143.90 143.9958 143.90 143.9400  40769 2017-08-25 15:45:00
> 2350:         939 143.94 143.9500 143.87 143.8900  56616 2017-08-25 15:50:00
> 2351:         940 143.97 143.9700 143.89 143.9400  56381 2017-08-25 15:55:00
> 2352:         941 143.74 143.9700 143.74 143.9655 179811 2017-08-25 16:00:00
> ```

---

Used data:

```
DT <- fread('https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=300&p=30d&f=d,t,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=IBM', skip = 7, header = FALSE)
setnames(DT, 1:6, c('date','close','high','low','open','volume'))
```

Comment: I get the following warning with this; Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(DT[grep("^a", date), `:=`(datetime, as.integer(gsub("\\D+",  :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 2352 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.

Comment: @redbaron1981 I get that too, but nothing to worry about. It just sais that it changed the class to integer.